# Asymptotic behaviour from Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform

Given the Fourier transform $G(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{A + B k^4}$ of a function $G(\vec{x})$, I wish to infer the asymptotic behaviour of $G(\vec{x})$ as $|{\vec{x}}| \to \infty$. Note that $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A,B > 0$. I thought of writing $G(\vec{x}/a)$, doing u-substitutions in the integrals and eventually expanding in a series for $a$ close to $0$, but this got me nowhere. Does anyone have any hints on how to proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's define Fourier Transformation as
$$F(\vec k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\vec x) e^{-i(\vec k,\vec x)} d^2x$$
Thus,
$$f(\vec x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\vec k) e^{i(\vec k,\vec x)} d^2k=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2B}\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{ikx\cos\phi}}{a+k^4} d\phi$$
where $a=\frac{A}{B}$.

But
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ikx\cos\phi}d\phi=2\pi J_0(kx)$$
We can also express the Bessel function (please, look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9) - formula 10.9.8) in the form
$$J_0(z)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\sin(z\cosh t)dt\,\,(z>0)$$
The integrand in our case is even, and we can write
$$f(\vec x)=f(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi^2 B}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx\cosh t)}{a+k^4}kdk=\frac{1}{4\pi^2 B}\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx\cosh t}}{a+k^4}kdk$$
To evaluate $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx\cosh t}}{a+k^4}k\,dk$ we integrate in the complex plane, adding a big half-circle in the upper half-plane. The integrand declines rapidly enough, so the integral along this half-circle tends to zero as the radius tends to $\infty$. The integrand has two poles inside the contour.
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx\cosh t}}{a+k^4}kdk=2\pi i Res_{\binom{k=a^{1/4}e^{\pi i/4}}{k=a^{1/4}e^{3\pi i/4}}}\frac{e^{ikx\cosh t}}{a+k^4}$$
Residues evaluation is straightforward:
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt a}\big(e^{-a^{1/4}x\cosh t\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}}-e^{-a^{1/4}x\cosh t\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}}\big)$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi B\sqrt a}\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c\cosh t}dt$$
where we denoted $c=a^{1/4}xe^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}$.

To find the asymptotics of the integral at $x\to\infty$ we use the steepest descent method. The saddle point is $t=0$. Near this point $\cosh t\approx 1+\frac{t^2}{2}$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c\cosh t}dt\sim\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-c(1+\frac{t^2}{2})}dt=e^{-c}\sqrt\frac{2\pi}{c}$$
$$\Im \,e^{-c}\sqrt\frac{2\pi}{c}=\Im \Bigg(e^{-a^{1/4}x\frac{1-i}{\sqrt 2}}\sqrt\frac{2\pi}{a^{1/4}xe^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}}\Bigg)=\sqrt\frac{2\pi}{a^{1/4}x}e^{-\frac{a^{1/4}x}{\sqrt 2}}\sin\Big(\frac{a^{1/4}x}{\sqrt 2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\Big)$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{Ba^{5/8}}\frac{e^{-\frac{a^{1/4}x}{\sqrt2}}}{\sqrt x}\sin\Big(\frac{a^{1/4}x}{\sqrt 2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\Big)\,, \,\, a=\frac{A}{B}, \,\,x\gg1$$
I would recommend to check the calculations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of that integral expression for the Bessel function!

Comment: @johnny I'm glad to help ) I would also recommend to use the tag "asymptotics" for this kind of problems. There are much more professional people than me who monitor the posts in this tag and can help quicker and better )

Comment: I'll add it to this post and I'll keep it in mind for the future!